# Opera Turbo or OBML specifications

Tags: opera, opera-turbo

i've got a tiny question
is there any open OBML or Opera Turbo protocol specifications accessible over the internet?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This same [question](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=261277&t=1303156591&page=1#comment2839038) is asked at a regular pace. The [OBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBML) language is at the heart of Opera Mini capabilities. It is not available under an open specification at this date.